# Manipulating objects in array to take the value of a property from objects in another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a sorted array of books with a property called 'place'.

book:

```
{
  id : number,
  place: string
}
```

but then I also have an array of places with the property 'name'

place

```
id: number,
name: string
```

What I'd like to do is to manipulate the array of books so that in the exact order,
the place property in a book takes the name value of the place object

result should be:

```
booksArr[0] == placeArr[0].name
booksArr[1] == placeArr[1].name
booksArr[2] == placeArr[2].name
```

and if the length of the placeArr > booksArr, then it should just ignore the rest, not do anything with it.

Is there any nifty way of doing that?

Comment: do you have some example data and wanted result?

Comment: You basically want to replace the entire books array with an array of place names? That doesn't really make sense, because then the books array is completely irrelevant. You need to noodle this out a little better before you post a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
book.forEach((_, ind) => {
    book[ind]["place"] = place[ind]["name"]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
const books = [...] // Your array of books
const places = [...] // Your array of places
books = books.map((book) => ({ id: book.id, place: places.find((place) => place.id === book.place)) });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate and use a short circuit for unequal arrays.

```
placeArray.some(({ name }, i) => {
    booksArray[i].place = name;
    return i + 1 >= booksArray.length;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, there's a pretty straightforward way to do that. You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create another array, with the values you want.

```
const booksWithPlace = booksArr.map((book, index) => {...book, place: placeArr[index]})
```